# Required Encryption configuration property missing: jasypt.encryptor.password

Tags: spring-boot, jasypt

Hi I'm trying to generate Jar file for my project, I'm using Jasypt to encrypt my jwtsecret. But whenever I try to do ***clean package*** in eclipse as goals to generate my jar file, I get this error *Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Required Encryption configuration property missing: jasypt.encryptor.password*.

This is the command that I have tried-

```
 mvn clean install -U dependency:copy-dependencies -Darguments="-Djasypt.encryptor.password=${tokensecretkey}"
```

Along with some other ones that I was using to do trial and hit. Can anyone help me here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following command generates the Jar file when using Jasypt:

```
mvn -B clean package -Djasypt.encryptor.password=<secret key>
```

and then below command can be used to run the generated Jar file:

```
java -jar -Djasypt.encryptor.password=<secret key> Your_jar_file.jar
```